# A board game called PALM BEACH or something to that effect

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone remember a board game called PALM BEACH or something to that effect that was played similar to monopoly ? I am looking for a copy or more info.

From what I can remember, The characters all started out with $1,000,000 dollars except "the count" who started out with $500,000 -- that is the most distinct memory of the game I have that might assist someone in remembering.

Does this sound familiar to anyone ?

Also, it was not "palm-beach-opoloy" nor was it a monopoly re-skin - it was a distinct game onto itself.

Followup Q&A:
Q: when did you play it ? 
A: it must have been around 20 years back

Comment: I guess it's not [this](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/26121/palm-beach-island-resort) then, since you say you played it 20 years ago.

Answer (score 19):

#### This must be it.

[image: Palm Beach]

1976 Board game:  *Palm Beach*

Source: http://www.palmbeachdailynews.com/news/lifestyles/blast-from-the-past-groovy-vintage-palm-beach-find/nWDNK/

Found an old ebay listing with more photos here: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-1976-Palm-Beach-Game-Complete-Monopoly-Style-Board-Entertaining-Fun-/230915467545?nma=true&si=w8Yhok%252BHv7Zg0Y1acAhEKk1lbZU%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557

Comment: Wow, Yes, that is it...

Comment: Now... the real question is, however, can you find another one for sale for around $20 ?

Comment: @ire_and_curses Why thank you sir! I am very proud of my google-fu. **flexes, breaks a rack of blade servers in half**

Comment: @user4889 It's a bummer that evidently you missed that ebay auction by about two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely was a reskin of Monopoly, [Palm Beachopoly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002QL6B2C).

Comment: Thanks, but that was not it (not a monopoly re-skin)

Answer (score 0):

Does this ring any bells? [Palm Beachopoly](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/toys-games-palm-beach-opoly-game/22913084):

> Want a slice of paradise? Palm Beachopoly will let you buy, sell and
>   build an empire in beautiful Palm Beach County, Florida even if it's
>   only on paper. This fun-filled game, which features a historic hotel,
>   local attractions, shopping districts, charitable foundations, and
>   much more is a perfect way to experience Palm Beach County...

Unfortunately, I haven't been successful in learning anything about the rules.

As an aside, there are a large number [of weird and wacky Monopoly-like games](http://www.epinions.com/kifm-Toys-All/skp_~1/dl_~/search_vertical_~all/search_string_~late-for-the-sky-palm-beachopoly-board-game) out there. I wouldn't expect too much gameplay depth, though...

Comment: The Barnes and Noble link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The only result for a search of "Palm Beach" on BoardGameGeek is "[Palm Beach Island Resort](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/26121/palm-beach-island-resort)"

There's almost no information available, but there is a brief description:

> Palm Beach Island Resort is described as a tactical game. By placing needed infrastructure onto the spaces of the Island, a tourist resort is created that will be visited by guests from around the world. The goal of the game is to build Bungalows and encourage the tourists to part with their money; that is, make a tidy profit. Each player acts as a travel agent trying to fill his bungalows up.

Perhaps this was it?

Comment: release date 2006, so cannot be what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @user1873 Ah, good point.

Answer (score 0):

I have the game.  It is a 1976 board game called "PALM BEACH" A GAME.  The box is lime green, pink and white with black lettering. Looks like a Lilly Pulitzer print.  It looks as though it has never been played.  The money, cards and playing pieces are in pristine condition as is the board.  The game is complete and includes the instructions.

Comment: you could improve this answer by looking at those instructions and checking to see if the details in the question (starting money, a count) match them. You could also include photos to help jog the asker's memory. Then this would actually answer the question. I will point out, though, that the asker has already accepted an answer identifying the game and that answer is a close match to your newer one. As it stands your answer isn't really adding any information, but you could edit it so that it does.